# test re compile compiled "on the fly" gives an empty match, not None

Tags: python, regex, python-re

I'm trying to test a bunch of regex cases (specifically if something is a unit of measurement: 5px, 300mm etc).

All the questions i can find about re.match tell me that i test this as follows:

```
import re

test_phrase_good = "5kw"
test_phrase_bad = "5XXX"
registered_units_regex = re.compile('[0-9]+kw|[0-9]+mm', re.IGNORECASE)

# test in the following way:
registered_units_regex.match(token) is not None

# so:
print(registered_units_regex.match(test_phrase_good)) # <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='5kw'>
print(registered_units_regex.match(test_phrase_bad)) #  None
```

As expected.

However, if i want to compile a regex in a loop, i get the following:

```
regex_units = [r"mm", r"kw"]
regex_string = r""
for unit in regex_units:
    regex_string += r'[0-9]+{}|'.format(unit)

regex_string = regex_string.rstrip('|')

registered_units_regex = re.compile(regex_string, re.IGNORECASE)
registered_units_regex.match(test_phrase_good) is not None

# so:
print(registered_units_regex.match(test_phrase_good)) # <re.Match object; span=(0, 3), match='5kw'>
print(registered_units_regex.match(test_phrase_bad)) #  <re.Match object; span=(0, 0), match=''>
```

which means i can no longer use `is None` as a test.

Why is this?  and how should I properly test for no match?

Comment: Your regexp matches an empty string because of `|` at the end.

Comment: Did you print `regex_string` after building it in the loop? You should notice that it is obviously different than the one in the first example.

Comment: @Barmar I apologies I stripped that in another version and removed it when trying tpo write a minimal example, the result is the same when stripping it- I've updated the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `|` at the end of the regexp means that it matches an empty string. You should only put `|` between the alternatives, not before or after them. You can use `join` to do that.

You also have `[0-9]+` in both `regex_units` and the format string, you don't need it in both places.

```
regex_units = ["mm","kw"]
regex_string = "|".join(r'[0-9]+{}|'.format(unit) for unit in regex_units)
```

Comment: I didn't notice that duplication, I've fixed it.

Comment: You have extra trailing `|`. It should be `'|'.join(r'[0-9]+{}'.format(unit) for unit in regex_units)`